# Strange Error Message when Using CMSIS 5.7 with STM CubeIDE during Code Generation

Tags: arm, stm32f4, cmsis, stm32cubeide

I get a strange Error Message during the Code-Generation Process in STM CubeIDE for a STM32F4 target:

[image: error message]

**The Details:**
I am using STM CubeIDE for an embedded Project with an STM32F405 Microcontroller and I have added the CMSIS Package 5.7.0 to the project, because i need some of the DSP functions. I have allready done this before and never experienced such an error message.

The message pops up during the Code-Generation process, after changing something in the Hardware-Setup with the (built in) CubeMX. It occurs two times during the Code Generation process. I can click on "OK" and it does NOT interrupt the Code Generation process, which seems to finish successfully. I can also compile the project without errors and it seems to work ok.

**The Question:**
Even though it seems to work properly, I'd like to know: what is this, where does it come from, and what can I do to solve this? I'm affraid that might lead to some unpleasant sleeping bugs or other nasty stuff ...

Has anyone experienced anything simlilar and has an explanation or even a solution for this?

Hint: I have recently update to CubeIDE 1.6.0 - maybe this is a Bug in CubeIDE and not in CMSIS?

**What I've done:**
I tried to google that, with the keywords:
"SliDtzliTZ&" and the "LogicalParser:syntax error detected in expression for ARM.CMSIS.5.7.0" but did not get any usefull results. Next step was to post the question here ...

Thank you in advance,
Chris

Comment: This question would be better asked on the ST support forums.  If enough people ask the same question there then ST might fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens with release version `5.7.0`. Using any older version available in the [official repository](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/releases/) solves the problem.

I'm using `5.6.0` now and all is fine.

Edit: Problem persists on `5.8.0`.